# General URL for restcall on both server and on development machine,

Tags: codeigniter, angularjs

My restcall on my devoplment machine is this:

```
 return $resource('http://127.0.0.1/projectname/index.php/api/pipedata/pipes/format/json', {}, {});
```

Since I have several projects on my dev machine, I cant have it on root.

But on my server I have it on root so the correct url is:

```
http://127.0.0.1/index.php/api/pipedata/pipes/format/json
```

"projectname" is removed.

Whats the best practice to solve this? On server or client side?

I have php with codeigniter on server and angular js on client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a config file for different environment with an variable called `ApiDomain` like this

In dev configuration `config_dev.js`:

```
config = {};
config.ApiDomain = 'http://127.0.0.1/projectname';
```

In prod configuration `config_prod.js`:

```
config.ApiDomain = 'http://127.0.0.1';
```

Then in code you can refer to `config.ApiDomain`

```
return $resource(config.ApiDomain +'/index.php/api/pipedata/pipes/format/json', {}, {});
```

When deploy your code you can rename `config_dev.js` or `config_prod.js` to `config.js` for dev or prod in CI and you only need to refer to `config.js` in your code.